# Removing text captions in NSIS UltraModernUI

Tags: installation, nsis

I have created an installer using NSIS and the Ultra Modern UI. The installer uses a BG image for the background, and the small setting  of UltraModernUI, for a smaller window.

This means that the default text of some pages, eg on the License page "License Agreement  Please review the license terms before installing X" are interfering with the background image. I have tried to set all the text captions to blank, but it doesn't seem to work. Is it
possible to remove this text?

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

```
 !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
 !define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "" ;the subtitle in the header will be empty
 !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "license.txt"
```

You can define the text on nearly every page.

For the license page:

MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT text

MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT text

MUI_LICENSEPAGE_TEXT_TOP text

MUI_LICENSEPAGE_TEXT_BOTTOM text

check out the docu:

http://ultramodernui.sourceforge.net/Readme.php

in section page settings ;)